# How to code a SEQUENCE OF inside a SEQUENCE OF (asn1 to c)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, sequence, asn.1

I'm working with vanetza to make cpms messages, I have built the .c and .cpp files from the asn1, so the structures of the message have the structure of the asn1. I have a structure (PerceptionDataContainer) which is a SEQUENCE OF PerceptionData, the Sequence of is a special type of list. Each PerceptionData have a perceivedobjects structure which is a SEQUENCE OF PerceivedObject struct, I have made this code to add information to these struct;

```
    vanetza::asn1::Cpm cpm;

    auto object = asn1::allocate<PerceivedObject_t>(); //this fill the struct PerceivedObject with basic info
    auto perception = asn1::allocate<PerceptionData_t>();

    PerceivedObject *arrayobjeto[2];

    cpm->cpm.cpmParameters.perceptionData = asn1::allocate<CpmParameters::CpmParameters__perceptionData>();

    cpm->header.protocolVersion=2;
    cpm->header.messageID=ItsPduHeader__messageID_cpm;
    cpm->header.stationID=1;
    cpm->cpm.cpmParameters.managementContainer.stationType=2;

    for(int i=0; i<2;i++) {
        arrayobjeto[i]=asn1::allocate<PerceivedObject>();
        arrayobjeto[i]->objectID= i+1;
        arrayobjeto[i]->timeOfMeasurement = TimeOfMeasurement_oneMilliSecond;
        arrayobjeto[i]->xDistance.value = DistanceValue_oneMeter;
        arrayobjeto[i]->xDistance.confidence = DistanceConfidence_oneMeter;
        arrayobjeto[i]->yDistance.value = DistanceValue_oneMeter;
        arrayobjeto[i]->yDistance.confidence = DistanceConfidence_oneMeter;
        arrayobjeto[i]->xSpeed.value = SpeedValueExtended_oneCentimeterPerSec;
        arrayobjeto[i]->xSpeed.confidence = SpeedConfidence_equalOrWithinOneMeterPerSec;
        arrayobjeto[i]->ySpeed.value = SpeedValueExtended_oneCentimeterPerSec;
        arrayobjeto[i]->ySpeed.confidence = SpeedConfidence_equalOrWithinOneMeterPerSec;
    }
    perception->containerId=1;
    perception->containerData.present=PerceptionData__containerData_PR_PerceivedObjectContainer;
    perception->containerData.choice.PerceivedObjectContainer.numberOfPerceivedObjects=1;

    for(int i=0; i<2;i++) {
        EXPECT_EQ(0, ASN_SEQUENCE_ADD(&perception->containerData.choice.PerceivedObjectContainer.perceivedObjects,arrayobjeto[i]));
    }
    EXPECT_EQ(0, ASN_SEQUENCE_ADD(&cpm->cpm.cpmParameters.perceptionData->list, perception));
    EXPECT_EQ(1, cpm->cpm.cpmParameters.perceptionData->list.count);
    EXPECT_EQ(2, cpm->cpm.cpmParameters.perceptionData->list.array[0]->containerData.choice.PerceivedObjectContainer.perceivedObjects.list.count);
    EXPECT_EQ(perception, cpm->cpm.cpmParameters.perceptionData->list.array[0]);
    EXPECT_EQ(arrayobjeto[0], cpm->cpm.cpmParameters.perceptionData->list.array[0]->containerData.choice.PerceivedObjectContainer.perceivedObjects.list.array[0]);


    EXPECT_TRUE(cpm.validate());
    EXPECT_FALSE(cpm.encode().empty());
    ByteBuffer buffer = cpm.encode();
    std::cout << "tamaño: " << buffer.size() << "\n";
    for (const auto byte:buffer){
        printf("%02x ",byte);
    }
    
    ASSERT_TRUE(cpm.decode(buffer));
    std::cout << cpm.size();
```

The definitions of the structs are these:

```
typedef struct CpmParameters {
    CpmManagementContainer_t     managementContainer;
    struct OriginatingStationData   *stationDataContainer;  /* OPTIONAL */
    struct CpmParameters__perceptionData {
        A_SEQUENCE_OF(struct PerceptionData) list;
        
        /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
        asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
    } *perceptionData;

....

typedef struct PerceptionData {
    CpmContainerId_t     containerId;
    struct PerceptionData__containerData {
        PerceptionData__containerData_PR present;
        union PerceptionData__containerData_u {
            SensorInformationContainer_t     SensorInformationContainer;
            PerceivedObjectContainer_t   PerceivedObjectContainer;
            FreeSpaceAddendumContainer_t     FreeSpaceAddendumContainer;
        } choice;
        
        /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
        asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
    } containerData;

....

typedef struct PerceivedObjectContainer {
    NumberOfPerceivedObjects_t   numberOfPerceivedObjects;  /* DEFAULT 0 */
    struct PerceivedObjectContainer__perceivedObjects {
        A_SEQUENCE_OF(struct PerceivedObject) list;
        
        /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
        asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
    } perceivedObjects;
    
    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} PerceivedObjectContainer_t;
```

I have reached a good encode but it can not be decode correctly and it seems I have loaded the data into the structs not perfectly, anyone knows how to do it correctly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please pick language tags matching your language. This code is C++, not C. They are very different languages.

Comment: Is that test code actually assert correct encoding? I don't recognise the style of the generated code. The two lines seem to be first testing that the object to be serialised is not empy, and then encoding cpm but without checking that encoding was actually successful. A way to verify things is to use the ASN.1 playground on OSS-Nokalva's website. Put your schema into that, also put in your serialistion, and see if that can decode it.